# react - what is slower: VDOM rendering or reconcilation/diffing?

Tags: reactjs

In react when a component tree is re-rendered then there are three stages:

1) generating new vdom by calling the component's `render()` methods, this process generates the new VDOM

2) comparing the newly generated VDOM with the previous VDOM, locating the changes

3) mutating the DOM so that it becomes in sync with the new VDOM

**Question:**

Which one is slower: step 1) or step 2) ?

Is the speed of step 2) affected by `shouldComponentUpdate()` at all?

**Reason for asking:**

I am asking this because I would like to understand how to better take advantage of the `shouldComponentUpdate` method.

More precisely, I devised a method that needs to render the VDOM and then based on that it can tell very accurately which component needs to be re-rendered (by using `shouldComponentUpdate` with this knowledge).

I understand that this approach is not going to help with speeding up step 1) but it can help to speed up step 2), in effect, by automatically generating the most optimal "implementations" of the `shouldComponentUpdate`   methods for all the components during step 1).

So this would be a general way to speed up diffing but I am not sure if it is worth it.